# IBM Maximo: Start Center and Multiple Tables

Tags: maximo

I am trying to help a colleague out. I created a query in IBM Maximo 7.6, it is in the work orders table but I added a sub query that pulls from the workflow table and filters for anything in Work Flow.

My question is: On the start center, is there anyway to modify the results set so that we can pull fields from work order and work flow? I have work number, status, and vehicle. Basically, is it possible to bring in what inbox the work order is in, on the results set, in graphical form. So, put together a bar graph based on the inbox?

Any direction would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure there is a Relationship on the WORKORDER object in Database Configuration that will find the workflow record you want to see info from for a given work order. Once you've done that, [these instructions](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21980423) show you, step by step, how to create Report Object Structure (ROS) (an Object Structure "Consumed By" Reporting), how to grant access to the ROS, and then how to use the ROS in a Result Set portlet to access data in related objects.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Those instructions are great, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the question as answered.